# How to convert video to all possible codecs?

Tags: php, ffmpeg

im tryin to find codecs that works on [awesomium](https://ripcode.net/p/awesomium) (chromium 18 iirc).
To got this ive made a simple php script that automatically does this.

```php
<?php
    $result = shell_exec("ffmpeg -codecs");
    $codecs = preg_split("/\r\n|\n|\r/", $result);

    for ($i = 10; $i < count($codecs) - 1; $i++) {
        $codec = $codecs[$i];
        $split = explode(" ", $codec);
        $info = $split[1];
        if ($info[2] == "V" && $info[1] == "E") { # video codec & encoding supported
            $codec = $split[2];
            #echo($codec ."\n");
            shell_exec("ffmpeg -i 'test.mp4' -c:v $codec 'result/$codec.mp4'");
        }
    }
?>
```

But I have a problem - ffmpeg requires specifying the correct extension of the output file to determine whats container should be used.
Is there any way to get the file extension knowing the codec name?
Or maybe there is some arguments for ffmpeg that will allows to write a file in any extension (I could just save all the files with `.mp4` ext, the browser determines how it plays the video not by the file extension).
Or maybe there are other utilities besides ffmpeg that will help me do this.

Answer (score 0):

`ffmpeg -h muxer=<muxer>` shows common extensions as well as the default video codec.

`ffmpeg -muxers` shows all muxers (similar to `-codecs`).

Taking the list of video codecs for encoding and then comparing against the list of muxers which have their default video codec one of that list, results in the following table:

| codec | muxer | common extension |
| --- | --- | --- |
| a64_multi | a64 | a64, A64 |
| apng | apng | apng |
| bmp | ico | ico |
| cinepak | film_cpk | cpk |
| dirac | dirac | drc, vc2 |
| dnxhd | dnxhd | dnxhd, dnxhr |
| dnxhd | mxf_opatom | mxf |
| dvvideo | dv | dv |
| fits | fits | fits |
| flv1 | flv | flv |
| flv1 | swf | swf |
| gif | gif | gif |
| h261 | h261 | h261 |
| h263 | 3g2 | 3g2 |
| h263 | 3gp | 3gp |
| h263 | h263 | h263 |
| h264 | dash | mpd |
| h264 | f4v | f4v |
| h264 | h264 | h264, 264 |
| h264 | hls | m3u8 |
| h264 | ipod | m4v, m4a, m4b |
| h264 | ismv | ismv, isma |
| h264 | matroska | mkv |
| h264 | mov | mov |
| h264 | mp4 | mp4 |
| h264 | psp | mp4, psp |
| hevc | hevc | hevc, h265, 265 |
| mjpeg | image2 | bmp, dpx, jls, jpeg, jpg, ljpg, pam, pbm, pcx, pgm, pgmyuv, png, ppm, sgi, tga, tif, tiff, jp2, j2c, j2k, xwd, sun, ras, rs, im1, im8, im24, sunras, xbm, xface, pix, y |
| mjpeg | mjpeg | mjpg, mjpeg |
| mjpeg | mpjpeg | mjpg |
| mpeg1video | mpeg | mpg, mpeg |
| mpeg1video | mpeg1video | mpg, mpeg, m1v |
| mpeg2video | dvd | dvd |
| mpeg2video | gxf | gxf |
| mpeg2video | mpeg2video | m2v |
| mpeg2video | mpegts | ts, m2t, m2ts, mts |
| mpeg2video | mxf | mxf |
| mpeg2video | svcd | vob |
| mpeg2video | vob | vob |
| mpeg2video | wtv | wtv |
| mpeg4 | avi | avi |
| mpeg4 | m4v | m4v |
| mpeg4 | nut | nut |
| msmpeg4v3 | asf | asf, wmv, wma |
| msmpeg4v3 | asf_stream | asf, wmv, wma |
| png | aiff | aif, aiff, afc, aifc |
| png | flac | flac |
| png | mp3 | mp3 |
| rawvideo | filmstrip | flm |
| rawvideo | rawvideo | yuv, rgb |
| roq | roq | roq |
| rv10 | rm | rm, ra |
| theora | ogg | ogg |
| theora | ogv | ogv |
| vp8 | ivf | ivf |
| vp9 | webm | webm |
| webp | webp | webp |
| wrapped_avframe | yuv4mpegpipe | y4m |

Most likely you want to do the mapping your own as you do not want to support all ffmpeg can encode.